# When do I use "was" and when do I use "were"

Tags: singular-vs-plural

Do I use *was* or *were* in this sentence?

> Bonnie, along with her associates, was invited to the gathering.

Answer (score 3):

The trick here is the use of the comma.  Here, the two commas are used to provide additional, but not essential, information.  Bonnie WAS.

Answer (score 2):

They were. (Plural)

She was. (Singular)

"Bonnie and her associates" are "they" so you would say were:

> Bonnie and her associates were invited to the gathering.

However, in your sentence, the associates are not part of the subject, so you would say:

> Bonnie, along with her associates, was invited to the gathering.